# Most efficient way to create searchable "array" in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, dictionary, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I would like to create a multidimensional array of some description in VB.NET that can store and search the following data efficiently (search on the second dimension, to return the first).

| Folder | Ext |
| --- | --- |
| excel | xls |
| excel | xlsx |
| word | doc |
| word | docx |
| powerpoint | ppt |
| powerpoint | pptx |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
    {"xls",  "excel"},
    {"xlsx", "excel"},
    {"doc",  "word"},
    {"docx", "word"},
    {"ppt",  "powerpoint"},
    {"pptx", "powerpoint"}
}
```

Access it like this:

```
Dim ext As String = "docx"
Dim folder As String = data(ext)
```

Comment: Do you know what, I'd looked at that, but got stuck with duplicate keys. Didn't even consider swapping the columns! Thank you!